# Outlook Express 6 - How can I transfer newsgroup messages to a new PC

Tags: migration, outlook-express, newsgroups

I use Outlook Express 6 to read newsgroups and had the messages from numerous servers downloaded on my PC.  The PC became unbootable, but with all files intact, and now I want to migrate the existing messages to the new installation of OE6 on the replacement disk.

I can't find any procedure for doing this. Just copying all files from the Store Folder doesn't seem to work.  OE starts to download the whole lot regardless if I try to synchronize.

Anybody know the secret?

*** MORE DETAILS ***

This is what I tried - I carried out the following steps:

- found the new OE ID folder
- deleted all files in there
- copied the files from old OE ID folder
- started OE.

My emails are visible.  The news servers I have newly added are visible but no newsgroups.  If I subscribe to some newsgroups it loads the headers for the messages since I last sync'd on the old machine, but I can't see the old existing messages.  For newsgroups with lots of messages on the server (like say >10k) it downloads (e.g.) `291 messages, 291 unread, 28290 not downloaded` yet I can see the dbx file for that group is 74 MB.

Comment: Your new user profile has a new OE ID. Did you copy them to the correct place? Do all the groups show up? Do emails show up?

Comment: The groups don't show up and OE creates a new DBX file and calls it `whatever.group (1).dbx` for the ones I have resubscribed to.  I downloaded a utility `MailView` which loads the old message DBX files OK and shows all my old messages.  It won't load `Folders.DBX` though, although that could be a different format.  If I inspect `Folders.dbx` and look at the binary I can see all the old newsgroups in there.

Comment: Just so you know, outlook express has not been updated in over 10 years. Perhaps give Thunderbird a try for reading newsgroups and emails http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/

Answer (score 1):

> Just copying all files from the Store Folder doesn't seem to work.

When you re-installed Windows, your new user profile was assigned a new (randomly generated) OE identity. You need to either point OE to the backup copy of the message store, or copy the files to the new location.

You can change the message store to point to the backup from within OE:

```
Tools⇨Options⇨Maintenance⇨Store Folder⇨Change
```

You can manually copy the files as well. If your previous OE message store was in `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\<guid>` and you copied it to `D:\oebackup`, then you need to check `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities` to see what the new GUID is.

Make sure to copy the *original* `folders.dbx` because that is where OE stores all information about subscribed newsgroups and flags like what has been downloaded.

> The groups don't show up and OE creates a new DBX file and calls it whatever.group (1).dbx for the ones I have resubscribed to.

Then you can recover the messages by starting over (make sure to keep your backup copy intact).

1. Unsubscribe from the newsgroups
2. Close OE
3. Remove the newsgroup database (`.dbx`) files
4. Start OE
5. Set it to only download the minimum (50) headers at a time (*Options⇨Read*)

   - (You can set this to `1` in the registry, but it’s easier to just disconnect from the Internet, then it will still create the `.dbx` files for the groups, but not download *any* messages. You might however have to click the `[Stop]` button in the [*Send/Receive* dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORVgo.jpg) to avoid waiting for it to time out.)
6. Subscribe to the groups
7. Select the groups to have OE download one message for each one (and create `.dbx` files for them)
8. Close OE
9. Copy the corresponding files from the backup, over-witing the new ones
10. Start OE
11. Click each newsgroup to have OE detect the messages already stored and update `folders.dbx` as necessary
12. Reset the number of messages to download

    - **You may need to switch steps 11 and 12**

You can also give the tools at [OEHelp](http://www.oehelp.com/) a try to see if they can extract some messages, but if OE is not picking up the groups from your original backup copy, then something went wrong and it is broken (you said the system became un-bootable; whatever made it un-bootable could have caused `folders.dbx` to become corrupted).

Comment: Thanks.  I've added more detail to the question.  Folder.dbx is there.  I've found the new message store OK.

Comment: The datestamp on'Folders.dbx' on the old machine is yesterday, but that will be because I tried the OE `File/Import` function yeaterday to import the email messages, hoping that might get the newsgroup messages as well.  'Folders.dbx' "looks" OK -i.e. has the old newsgroup names in there.

Comment: `The datestamp on'Folders.dbx' on the old machine is yesterday, because I tried the File/Import function yeaterday to import the email messages, hoping that might get the newsgroup messages as well.`   Is that `folders.dbx` in your backup or the one that was copied to the active message store? If it’s your original backup copy, then it has been modified. OE updated it with the information it had in the new installation, and thus over-wrote the old data. (Do you see your email sub-folders?) There’s no way to restore that information because it’s format is proprietary. Try the trick I suggested.

Comment: I'm currently following your steps with the files from my laptop's OE installation.  I can't find the option `only download one message (Options⇨Read)`.  Do you mean `Get nnn headers at a time` ? which won't let me specify less than 50.

Comment: Yes that’s the one. I added a note above for that step (5).